# Installing My Own Application via the MS Web Platform Installer

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, web-platform-installer

Can I use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer to install an application that I create? Everything I've seen/read so far seems to indicate it can be used to update IIS, download components as well as free software like WordPress etc. but I haven't found anything to indicate I can use it as a deploy tool for software I make.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload your app to the gallery but there are a couple of caveats.  From [**Scott Hanselman's post on this topic**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MicrosoftWebPlatformWebApplicationGalleryWebPlatformInstallerAndDasBlog.aspx):

> In order to upload to the gallery your
>   app should:
>
> 1. Be Current: The application you provide a link to must be the latest,
>      stable final release version
>      available, hosted on a publically
>      available Web URL
> 2. Be Free of Charge: The application for which you submit a link to the
>      Microsoft Web App Gallery must be
>      provided free of charge and fully
>      functional without time restrictions.
>      You are welcome to charge for
>      professional support or consulting
>      services and/or provide an enhanced,
>      enterprise version of the application
>      for purchase on your site.  We will be
>      happy to provide a link to your
>      commercial products and services from
>      your page in the Microsoft Web
>      Application Gallery.
> 3. Be Compatible: The application to which you provide a link must run on
>      Windows Server 2003, Windows Server
>      2008, Windows XP & Windows Vista using
>      best practices on running ASP.NET
>      applications and PHP applications on
>      IIS.
> 4. Be Deployable: The application to which you provide a link must
>      integrate with Microsoft Web Deploy as
>      described in the Microsoft Web
>      Application Packaging Guide, and run
>      with the Microsoft Web Platform
>      Installer v2.
> 5. Be Supported: You must provide a publicly available Web site where end
>      users can download your application,
>      find documentation and/or get free on
>      a best effort basis support through a
>      forum.
> 6. Be Hostable: The application to which you provide a link must run well
>      in a shared hosted environment as well
>      as when the user has administrative
>      rights for the computer.
> 7. Be Inclusive: If your link is included in the Gallery, you should
>      include a link on your application
>      community’s Web site to your
>      Application entry on the Microsoft Web
>      Application Gallery.
> 8. Be Safe: The application to which you provide a link must not harm
>      customers or be malicious, dishonest,
>      destructive, invasive, or act in any
>      manner restricted by the Web Gallery
>      Application Submission agreement.